# How to repeat the string only a certain number of times?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is a program that prints the pound sign in zag-zag formation. I want the program to stop after the "##########" string executes 50 times instead of the zig zag going on forever. How do i fix this?

````
import time
indent = 0
Increasing = True


try:
    while True:

        time.sleep(0.1)
        print(" " * indent, end = "")
        print("##########")
        repeat = repeat + 1
    
    
        if Increasing:
            indent = indent + 1
            if indent == 8:
                Increasing = False
        else:
            indent = indent - 1
            if indent == 0:
                Increasing = True
        
        
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()```
````

Comment: replace your `while True` by a `for` loop

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Did Almog solve your problem? Accepting an answer rewards the answerer with rep and shows others that your issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Use `for _ in range(50)` instead of `while True`